# How do I fix an error that does not allow Spyder to start?

Tags: python, anaconda, spyder, ctypes

Traceback (most recent call last):
File "C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\Scripts\spyder-script.py", line 6, in
from spyder.app.start import main
File "C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\spyder\app\start.py", line 21, in
import ctypes
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'ctypes'

I recently updated both python and Spyder to their newest versions. I tried to open Spyder, but came across this error where it cannot launch Spyder.

Comment: Python 3.11? What's the value of `sys.path`?  Might be related to https://github.com/python/cpython/issues/100320 where embedded Python 3.11 has a missing DLL path.

Comment: Python 3.9.12. How do I check the value of sys.path?

Comment: `import sys` and `print(sys.path)`  but it isn't related to the bug if it isn't 3.11.

Comment: FWIW, I ran that and got the following: ['C:\Users\Tony\Desktop\test', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\Lib', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\python39.zip', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\DLLs', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\lib\site-packages', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\win32\lib', 'C:\Users\Tony\anaconda3\lib\site-packages\Pythonwin']